# Getting binary content from Avro

Tags: apache-nifi

I have an ExecuteSQL processor that returns a SQL Server `varbinary` field for a particular row:

```
select [File]
from dbo.Attachment
where attachmentid=?
```

The query will find one row. The content gets stored in Avro. The retrieved `File` could be a text format (CSV, HTML, etc) or a binary format (PDF, Office docs, images, etc).

If the content is text, I can run it through ConvertAvroToJSON and then EvaluateJsonPath to get the content that I want. That doesn't work with the binary content, however. When I download the content of a flowfile that has, say, a PowerPoint file, PowerPoint complains about the content.

I'd like to have the Content of my FlowFile be just the binary content (I'll be sending it on to a PutMarkLogic processor later). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not test it.

but you could use ExecuteGroovyScript as workaround to write binary field directly to a file content.

`SQL.mydb` - add this parameter on the level of [processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-groovyx-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript/SQL.gif) and link it to required DBCP pool.

`AttributeWithID` - i assume there is a flow file attribute with this name that contains value to be used in sql query for `attachmentid`

```groovy
def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return

SQL.mydb.eachRow("""
    select [File]
    from dbo.Attachment
    where attachmentid=${ff.AttributeWithID}
"""){row->
    ff.write{outStream-> 
        outStream << row.getBinaryStream(1)
    }
}
REL_SUCCESS << ff
```